# Pattern based punctuation using Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

As a test, using Spacy I am punctuating text after identifying with span.

```
import spacy, en_core_web_sm
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

# Read input file
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
Punctuation_patterns = [[{'POS': 'NOUN'},{'POS': 'NOUN'},{'POS': 'NOUN'}],
                        ]

matcher.add('PUNCTUATION', None, *Punctuation_patterns)
doc = nlp("The cat cat cat sat on the mat. The dog sat on the mat.")
matches = matcher(doc)
spans = []
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]  # the matched slice of the doc
    spans.append({'start': span.start_char, 'end': span.end_char})
    layer1 = (' '.join(['"{}"'.format(span.text)if token.dep_ == 'ROOT'  else '{}'.format(token) for token in doc]))
    print (layer1)
```

Output:

```
The cat cat cat "cat cat cat" on the mat . The dog "cat cat cat" on the mat .
```

Expected output

```
The "cat cat cat" sat on the mat. The dog sat on the mat.
```

I am just testing with ROOT, how to identify span matches using spacy to get desired output?

**Edit 1:** In case of multiple detection like dog dog dog

```
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]  # the matched slice of the doc
    spans.append({'start': span.start_char, 'end': span.end_char})
    result = doc.text

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    result = result.replace(span.text, f'"{span.text}"', 1)
    print (result)
```

Current output:

```
The "cat cat cat" sat on the mat. The dog dog dog sat on the mat.
The "cat cat cat" sat on the mat. The "dog dog dog" sat on the mat.
```

Expected:

```
  The "cat cat cat" sat on the mat. The "dog dog dog" sat on the mat.
```

Comment: `sat` is identified as `ROOT` here.

Comment: `result = doc.text`, then `for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    result = result.replace(span.text, f'"{span.text}"', 1)` and then `print(result)` will output what you need.

Comment: Does solve the issue but repeats sentences. Please see Edit1.

Comment: No,  there should be no indent before `print (result)`. Only print it once after the for loop is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
result = doc.text
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    result = result.replace(span.text, f'"{span.text}"', 1)
print (result)
```

That is, you defne a variable to keep the result, `result`, and assign it with the `doc.text` value. Then, you go throug the matches and replace each matched span with the same span text wrapped with double quotation marks.